# Spring boot: spring-data-elasticsearch how to set ignore_unavailable query param

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Spring boot: spring-data-elasticsearch 5.1.5

how to we set ignore_unavailable=true for the search query?

That I look inside `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.RequestConverter` I cannot see support for '`ignore_unavailable`' param.

I am using NativeQueryBuilder to which I set Query created using `co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.QueryBuilder`

e.g. following is not helping

```
        new NativeQueryBuilder()
        .withQuery(query)
        .withPageable(pageable)
        .withIndicesOptions(IndicesOptions.LENIENT_EXPAND_OPEN)
        .build();
```

I am trying to produce following query:

```
POST /test_statements-2021-06-21,test_statements-2021-06-14,test_statements-2021-06-07,test_statements-2021-05-31,test_statements-2021-05-24,test_statements-2021-05-17/_search?typed_keys=true&max_concurrent_shard_requests=5&ignore_unavailable=true&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here are a couple of ways to fix it:

1. Check this [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482465/elastic-search-handling-missing-indices) question, it looks related to `IndicesOptions`.
2. Consider to use `index_pattern` rather than index name like `test_statements-*`.
3. Use [index alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/aliases.html#:%7E:text=An%20alias%20is%20a%20secondary,an%20alias%20at%20any%20time.) to automate the process. An alias can point multiple index for search, and can only point on index for indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You can set add *ignore_unavailable* like this:

```java
new NativeQueryBuilder()
        .withQuery(query)
        .withPageable(pageable)
        .withIndicesOptions(IndicesOptions.ofOptions(EnumSet.of(IndicesOptions.Option.IGNORE_UNAVAILABLE)))
        .build();
```

The predefined values like `IndicesOptions.LENIENT_EXPAND_OPEN` are predefined EnumSets of different option values, but as shown you can easily build your own.